# Difference between setAttribute and setAttributeNS(null,

Tags: javascript, attributes

What is the difference between calling setAttribute and setAttributeNS with null as the namespace parameter?

Also is there an issue with using getAttribute() and then setAttributeNS ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**setAttribute()** is a DOM 1 function. **setAttributeNS()** is a DOM 2 function that resolves the problem of conflicting tag or attribute names by specifying the xmlns namespace that should apply to the tag/attribute in the first argument.

If an attribute does not have a defined namespace prefix, the first argument must be **null**. You could use **setAttribute()** but for consistency it is advisable to stick to **setAttributeNS()**. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course#Scripting_in_namespaced_XML

> "However, note carefully: the Namespaces in XML 1.1 recommendation
>   states that the namespace name for attributes without a prefix does
>   not have a value. In other words, although the attributes belong to
>   the namespace of the tag, you do not use the tag's namespace name.
>   Instead, you must use null as the namespace name for unqualified
>   (prefixless) attributes."

Comment: This leaves me somewhat confused. I'm working with SVG nodes and have never needed anything but `null` as the `namespace` argument. Can I just replace it with `setAttribute()` everywhere?

Comment: This answer works for regular SVG attributes without a namespace such as `width`, but does not work for the `xmlns` attribute. It is prefixless, so `setAttributeNS(null, "xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")` should work for it, but it does not work in Firefox (throws error: "An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces"), and I don't see any bugs about it on BugZilla. `setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")` works though.

Answer (score 1):

The setAttributeNS method is an XML method, and will not work with HTML elements.

Comment: I'm using this for SVG only.  I'm trying to modify an attribute in a SVG dom rendered using Batik and Java.   I modify the attribute with setAttributeNS() and I can see the value change in the DOM, but it doesn't change on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation in English, from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttributeNS):

```
// Given:
//   <div id="div1" xmlns:special="http://www.mozilla.org/ns/specialspace"
//     special:specialAlign="utterleft" width="200px" /> 

d = document.getElementById("div1"); 
d.removeAttributeNS("http://www.mozilla.org/ns/specialspace", "specialAlign"); 

// Now:
//   <div id="div1" width="200px" />
```

So from this, it appears that `xmlns:special="http://www.mozilla.org/ns/specialspace"` is a declaration of the namespace `special`, which is then used to contextualize `special:specialAlign`.

Answer (score -1):

`setAttributeNS` is used for specifying the namespace and adds a new attribute with a  namespace. `NS` represent that. Also it requires three parameters

```
element.setAttributeNS(ns,name,value)

ns  :namespace URI of the attribute to set
name:Name of the attribute to set
value:Value of the attribute to set

setAttribute(name,value) which is use to add a new attribute or change the value of existing attribute.
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the primary question on leaving NS = null