# setAttributeNS won't allow null

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg

I'm converting some JavaScript to Typescript.

In the following code, null is rejected on the basis that it cannot be assigned to a string parameter.

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', canvas.width.toString());
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', canvas.height.toString());
```

Inspecting the type of `svg`, we find that it is `SVGSVGElement` (yes, SVG occurs twice in the name). I tried explicitly specifying a type `svg: SVGElement` and was able to assign the created element to it, but there was no effect on the null problem.

The accepted answer to [Difference between setAttribute and setAttributeNS(null,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057909/difference-between-setattribute-and-setattributensnull) says I *must* pass null when the attribute has no defined namespace. It then advises me to use `setAttributeNS` "for consistency".

But I *can't* pass null. Should I pass an empty string? Would that work? or should I use the DOM level 1 `setAttribute` method?

Comment: Kind of not answering the question, but shouldn't you be specifying the namespace to be `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` ?

Comment: @GregHNZ - Actually, no. In the text of the answer I linked there is a discussion of this.

Comment: Just use setAttribute. Less typing overall.

Comment: There is a good reason the DOM object for `<svg>` is named `SVGSVGElement`. It's the same reason that the `<html>` element class is named `HTMLHtmlElemnt`.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau - and what is that reason? Namespacing?

Comment: Basically yes. The first "SVG" is the specification. The second is the element. `SVGSVGElement` corresponds to the `<svg>` element. `SVGPathElement` corresponds to the `<path>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the documentation says null is allowed then this seems like an oversight in the definition unfortunately.

Fortunately you can easily work around it. Typescript supports interface declaration merging so you can redeclare the `Element` interface in your file and add the missing method:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
interface Element {
    setAttributeNS(namespaceURI: null, qualifiedName: string, value: string): void;
}
declare var canvas : HTMLCanvasElement;

svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', canvas.width.toString());
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', canvas.height.toString());
```

Comment: Great answer which I have used, except because I'm pedantic it's `namespaceURI: string | null` also I had to do it to SVGSVGElement and explicitly type `svg: SVGSVGElement`

Comment: And merging failed hiding other methods so I ended up declaring an interface NSfix and casting for the call `(svg as NSfix).setAttributeNS(null, ...)`

Comment: @PeterWone What methods is it hiding ? The interface should be declared at top level and not in any namespace. From my experiments, all methods are still there.

Comment: Well the way I wrote it wasn't explicitly in a namespace or module but it's an Aurelia view-model so that may well be the issue.. Either way, casting with an interface is the answer so thank you.