# setAttributeNS xmlns of <svg> for a general-purpose library

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, svg

It appears web browsers throw a `DOMException` when one uses `setAttributeNS` on a `<svg>` element to set the `xmlns` attribute. i.e.

```
>>> s = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
<svg>​</svg>​

>>> s.setAttributeNS(null, 'xmlns', '123')
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' 
  on 'Element': '' is an invalid namespace for attributes.

>>> s.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'xmlns', 
      'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' 
  on 'Element': '' is an invalid namespace for attributes.

>>> s.setAttributeNS(null, 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' 
  on 'Element': '' is an invalid namespace for attributes.
```

The [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course#Scripting_in_namespaced_XML) recommend always using `setAttributeNS`, however it makes no mention of this possibility.  So the recommendation appears to have caveats.

The [DOM Level 2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-ElSetAttrNS) on `setAttributeNS` gives some insight:

> NAMESPACE_ERR: Raised if the qualifiedName is malformed, if the qualifiedName has a prefix and the namespaceURI is null, if the qualifiedName has a prefix that is "xml" and the namespaceURI is different from "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", or if the qualifiedName is "xmlns" and the namespaceURI is different from "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/".

So this particular exception appears to be part of a broader set of cases that could fail.  It's not immediately apparent what those cases are.

I'm writing tko / Knockout 4.0, a general-purpose web framework, and so it should support `svg` and other tags outside the core HTML namespace.

The most encountered problem comes from `xmlns` on `svg` tags so it's [an issue](https://github.com/knockout/tko/issues/85).  I've [worked around this](https://github.com/knockout/tko/blob/master/packages/utils.jsx/src/JsxObserver.js#L319) by specifically checking to see if `xmlns` is being set and using `setAttribute` in that case.

That workaround seems quite specific and I'm concerned about the general case.  Is there a precedent for how to generally handle setting attributes with `setAttributeNS` and `setAttribute`?

The other web frameworks don't address this neatly — it's generally mixed with other logic; the most on-point commit I've seen is for [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/92084f2b6a7cc1c81e31b8f413424223e62806d8), but it's not directly addressing this problem.

Related: [Difference between setAttribute and setAttributeNS(null,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057909)

Comment: When I create an SVG I use `var svg = document.createElementNS(ns.svg, "svg");` where `ns.svg: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to force compliance to the spec and _set_ the `xmlns` namespaceURI if it's encountered - and, for the same reason, _set_ the `xml` namespaceURI if it has been used as a prefix?

Comment: @ccprog TKO does indeed set the `xmlns` according to the spec, and that is the better approach, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: i.e. `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "svg").setAttributeNS(null, 'xmlns', '...')` throws

Comment: What I meant was, in the method you quoted, something like `var ns = name === 'xmlns' ? 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' : null;` `node.setAttributeNS(ns, name, String(value))`

Comment: @ccprog The `setAttributeNS` fails no matter what the `ns` is given; I've updated the question to reflect.

Comment: You are giving the `xmlns` attribute a `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace, but it needs to have the `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` namespace.

Comment: Why do you think that?  [mdn says 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) and that is prevalent, and in any case `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns', 'svg').setAttributeNS(null, 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns')` still fails.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not cover all cases, but this should go a long way:

```
const NAMESPACES = {
  svg: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
  html: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
  xml: 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace',
  xlink: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
  xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' // sic for the final slash...
}

class JsxObserver extends LifeCycle {
  ...

  setNodeAttribute (node, name, valueOrObservable) {
    const value = unwrap(valueOrObservable)
    NativeProvider.addValueToNode(node, name, valueOrObservable)
    if (value === undefined) {
      node.removeAttributeNS(null, name)
    } else if (isThenable(valueOrObservable)) {
      Promise.resolve(valueOrObservable)
        .then(v => this.setNodeAttribute(node, name, v))
    } else {
      const [prefix, ...unqualifiedName] = name.split(':')
      let ns = null
      if (prefix === 'xmlns' || unqualifiedName.length && NAMESPACES[prefix]) {
        ns = NAMESPACES[prefix]
      }
      node.setAttributeNS(ns, name, String(value))
    }
  }
}
```

If the attribute encountered is `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, it will be added with

```
.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
```

If the attribute encountered is `xml:space="preserve"` (something that SVG editors notoriously use), it will be added with

```
.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace', 'xml:space', 'preserve')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @ccprog; should there be an `else` to the `if (unqualifiedName.length ...)` that calls plain `setAttribute`?  I noted that's what Vue and Angular seem to be doing

Comment: Incidentally, I'll be adding some unit test cases to try out the spectrum of possibilities, and will report back once I have a chance to put that together.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I've edited some time forth and back and it got inconsistent.

Comment: No problem, I'm grateful for the assistance! I've other things to do right now, so I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: On second thought, is this a library specifically for JSX? in this case, the namespaced attributes will be written in camelCase, like `xlinkHref`, see https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html - that would probably need a RegExp to catch.

Comment: Good point re. JSX; we're complying with the JSX spec (https://facebook.github.io/jsx/), which seems to accommodate `:` namespace separators, but I'll keep this in mind for future revisions if folks encounter problems or want to translate React over to Knockout/JSX.

Comment: For anyone coming across this looking to add xlink to an svg tag as well, this is the answer: `el.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')` - thanks for the hints.