# Dynamically added SVG element does not appear even with createElementNS

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, dynamic

[The html code and how it shows up on the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0b8K.png)

Hello, I am starting to learn some web development. It has been going well, until I tried to dynamically generate some SVG rectangles in a group. But even though the code shows up on the inspector, when I hover over the dynamically generated rectangle code, it says "Rect 0x0", and does not visually appear. I have searched many other posts, but I have not found a solution.

```
function getMousePosition(svg, event) {
    var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
    if (event.touches) { event = event.touches[0]; }
    return {
        x: (event.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
        y: (event.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
    };
}
var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", elemWidth = 80, elemHeight = 40, slotWidth = 10, slotHeight = 10;

function spawnElem(event){
    let svg = event.target;
    if(event.which == 3){
        let pos = getMousePosition(svg, event)
        spawnElemHelper(svg, pos.x, pos.y);
    }
}

function spawnElemHelper(svg, x, y){
    topLeft = {x: x - elemWidth / 2,
               y: y - elemHeight / 2
            };

    // group = document.createElementNS(NS, 'g');
    // group.classList.add('draggable-group');

    main = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect');
    main.setAttributeNS(NS, 'x', String(topLeft.x));
    main.setAttributeNS(NS, 'y', String(topLeft.y));
    main.setAttributeNS(NS, 'width', String(elemWidth));
    main.setAttributeNS(NS, 'height', String(elemHeight));
    main.setAttributeNS(NS, 'fill', 'blue');

    // slotInput = document.createElementNS(NS, 'rect');
    // slotInput.classList.add("slot");
    // slotInput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'x', String(topLeft.x));
    // slotInput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'y', String(topLeft.y + (elemHeight - slotHeight) / 2));
    // slotInput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'width', String(slotWidth));
    // slotInput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'height', String(slotHeight));
    // slotInput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'fill', 'yellow');

    // slotOutput = document.createElementNS(NS, 'rect');
    // slotOutput.classList.add("slot");
    // slotOutput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'x', String(topLeft.x + elemWidth - slotWidth));
    // slotOutput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'y', String(topLeft.y + (elemHeight - slotHeight) / 2));
    // slotOutput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'width', String(slotWidth));
    // slotOutput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'height', String(slotHeight));
    // slotOutput.setAttributeNS(NS, 'fill', 'yellow');

    // group.appendChild(main);
    // group.appendChild(slotInput);
    // group.appendChild(slotOutput);
    
    //svg.appendChild(group);
    svg.appendChild(main);
}
//var svg is the svg element in the HTML which has the id "canvas"
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('mousedown', spawnElem);
```

Comment: Just a quick guess: Could you try using the `toString()` method. not sure if `String()` works in JS.

Comment: No difference, but I should have used the toString method for numbers, thanks!

Comment: I tried out your code and the `getScreenCTM()` function fails since its a function of an svg element but your event target is the element with the id `canvas`.

Comment: Please try `main.setAttributeNS(null,` instead of `main.setAttributeNS(NS` Also you may try setAttribute instead

Comment: using setAttribute instead of setAttributeNS did the trick. No idea why though, I still have little idea about how XML namespaces work.

Comment: This answer explains why you need to use Null: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057909/difference-between-setattribute-and-setattributensnull

Answer (score 2):

SVG uses the namespace only for elements and not for attributes. The attributes are in the "empty" namespace. This is typical for XML (several formats do this) and namespaced attributes are required to use a prefix.

You can use `setAttribute()` or `setAttributeNS('', ...)`:

```js
const xmlns_svg = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

const svg = document.implementation.createDocument(xmlns_svg, 'svg', null);
svg.documentElement.setAttribute('width', '100');
svg.documentElement.setAttribute('height', '100');

const rect = svg.documentElement.appendChild(
  svg.createElementNS(xmlns_svg, 'rect')
);
rect.setAttribute('x', '25');
rect.setAttribute('y', '25');
rect.setAttribute('width', '50');
rect.setAttribute('height', '50');
rect.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');

document.querySelector('div.demo').appendChild(
  document.importNode(svg.documentElement, true)
);

const svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
document.querySelector('img.demo').setAttribute(
  'src',
  'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgData)
);
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>

<img class="demo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setAttribute instead of setAttributeNS.